# Strange voting activity on my answers

Tags: support

There is strange voting activity going on on my answers on EESE. Yesterday in a short span of time, I got about 150 points due to upvotes on a variety of answers, many of which were not very new.

Then today, the serial voting was reversed, taking away 150 points. Now again today it seems that I have another burst of upvotes.

I guess my main concern is that I don't want anyone to think I am somehow behind this. My second concern is just to satisfy my curiosity about what might be going on.

Comment: Just had this happen to me, and came to the meta to ask exactly this. Any clue what's causing this?

Comment: @Hearth apart from SamGibson's answer, no, I have no idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I guess my main concern is that I don't want anyone to think I am somehow behind this.

I will be offline soon as it's past end of day here. I just wanted to put your mind at rest: I've done a quick review of your account and I am 100% sure that you are **not** doing anything to cause this. There is no "adverse mark" on your account as a result of this.

What you are seeing is described in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) page from the Help Center.

You don't need to take any action.

There is actually a bit more going on, which should be kept private, and I will discuss that with the other mods. You may see further such voting "bursts" and subsequent corrections, but again, please don't take any action.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Glad to hear it.